# How value become value as an key in MonogoDB array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Explanation :
I want to convert the value as part of the key, in document 1  `"xyz"` replace with  `v` and in document 2, `"abc"` replace with `v`.
**Note:** there are multiple documents, which I don't know what could be the document 3 "sig_nam" value.

**Doc No. 1**

```
  "sig_nam": "xyz",
  "cont_name": "1",
  "t_v": [
   {
      "t": "2020-11-20T03:00",
      "v": 0
    },
    {
      "t": "2020-10-25T03:00",
      "v": 0
    }
]
}
```

**Doc No. 2**

```
{
  "sig_nam": "abc",
  "cont_name": "1",
  "t_v": [
   {
      "t": "2020-11-20T03:00",
      "v": 0
    },
    {
      "t": "2020-10-25T03:00",
      "v": 0
    }
]
}
```

---

**Expected Output Doc No. 1**

```
  "sig_nam": "xyz",
  "cont_name": "1",
  "t_v": [
   {
      "t": "2020-11-20T03:00",
      "xyz": 0
    },
    {
      "t": "2020-10-25T03:00",
      "xyz": 0
    }
]
}
```

**Expected Output Doc No. 2**

```
{
  "sig_nam": "abc",
  "cont_name": "1",
  "t_v": [
   {
      "t": "2020-11-20T03:00",
      "abc": 0
    },
    {
      "t": "2020-10-25T03:00",
      "abc": 0
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$map` to iterate loop of `t_v` array
- `$arrayToObject`, set `k` as `sig_nam` and `v` as count and same for `t`, wrap in to an array bracket, it will convert in to object

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      t_v: {
        $map: {
          input: "$t_v",
          in: {
            $arrayToObject: [[
              { k: "t", v: "$$this.t" },
              { k: "$sig_nam", v: "$$this.v" }
            ]]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mQVVMI1zz95)

Comment: I think you can move `{ t: "$$this.t" }` into `$arrayToObject` so you don't need `$mergeObjects`

Comment: yes you are right thanks for your comment. i will update my answer.

Comment: @turivishal,[same_issue_like_that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66224942/how-to-value-become-the-key-of-all-fields-in-mongo-db) _can you check it Thanks_